How to conditionally lock cells including the cell with the condition in google sheets?
the issue that I have is the following. In sheets I register the information for the guests of an Hotel. In column “A” I write the date of check in. In column “B” I write the name of the customer. In column “C” I write which room that is going to be given. Lastly in column “D” I write the word “confirmed” if the customer confirmed his or her stay.
How can I write “Confirmed” in column D and then immediately lock or reject input so that cell won’t be changed alongside the cells in column A,B and C?
So I write in the criteria in data validation that if the cell in column D says “confirmed”, then reject input for the cells in column A,B,C and D.
The issue is that if I want to write “confirmed” in column “D”, google sheets won’t let me (as expected). How can I write “Confirmed” in column D and then immediately lock or reject input in that same cell so it won’t be changed alongside the cells in column A,B and C?
